# text widthis different in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Thanks in advance.

JS Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/XpPpR/46/

here is my code,

```
<script src="Hide_3d5b7aca/Hide/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="measureText"/>
   <script>
       $(function () {
           text = "1 000 000";
           font = {
               color: '#282828', fontFamily: 'Segoe UI', fontStyle: 'Normal', fontWeight: 'regular', opacity: 1, size: '13px'
           };
           var element = $(document).find("#measureTex");
            if (element.length == 0) {
               var textObj = document.createElement('text');
               $(textObj).attr({ 'id': 'measureTex' });
               document.body.appendChild(textObj);
           }

            textObj.innerHTML = text;

           if (font != null) {
               textObj.style.fontSize = (font.size > 0) ? (font.size + "px") : font.size ;
               textObj.style.fontFamily = font.fontFamily ;
           }

           alert(textObj.offsetWidth);

       });
  </script>
```

the textwidth is shown as 57 in chrome and firefox , but in IE it return as 56.
why? and how to resolve this..

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the same text width in different browsers. This is because font rendering system is very different, especialy then comapre OS X and Windows.

More info: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

Comment: there is any source for this info?

Comment: @AkbarBasha, check this article for example: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/